# Why the dict.setdefault method in Python does not work as expected?

Tags: python

**from docs:**
*setdefault(key[, default])

If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.*
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

code:

```
def f():
    print('func work')
    return 33
d = {}
key = 'key'
print(d.setdefault(key,f()), '  - key not in dict')
print(d.setdefault(key,f()), '  - key in dict, but method "setdefault" not      return value, instead it run func again')
```

result:

> > Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
>   [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
>   > func work
>   > 33   - key not in dict
>   > func work
>   > 33   - key in dict, but method "setdefault" not return value, instead it run func again

Why?

Comment: `f()` is evaluated prior to the `d.setdefault` call.

Comment: because `setdefault` **takes a value, not a callabe**. This you would want to use `defaultdict` with just `f`, *not `f()`*. `f()` is evaluated **before** `d.setdefault(...)`

Comment: This is not question about how "functions evaluated when passed as parameters".
my question is :
why when I make second print - dict does not return value. 
Pair key:value is present and there is no anything about possibility of CHANGE value in method documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "dict does not return value"? It does return 33. `setdefault` does *not* change the key's value.

Comment: no. dict run f()

Comment: Have you actually read the top voted answer on the linked page? `f()` is evaluated before it reaches `setdefault`, the dictionary can't do anything about it.

Comment: yes. before. and after first call we have:
d = { 'key' : 33 } 
when second call I expeced thomething like this:

`if key in d.keys():  
        return d[key];  

d[key] = f();  

return d[key]`

Comment: Yeah, but that is not how `d.setdefault(key,f())` works internally.